# Kafka Connect Number type fields

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

When i would like to use Kafka connect with source RDBMS which is Oracle , Number type fields are seen as bytes like below,

Column "ID" with value "4" as number has been sent ,but at consumer console this value has been seen as "ID":"BA=="

What can i do in order to solve this issue ?

Kafka connect is started with below command

```
connect-standalone ./etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties /home/kafka/oracle.properties.test

######## connect-standalone.properties

# These are defaults. This file just demonstrates how to override some settings.
bootstrap.servers=kafkaserver01.localdomain:9092


# The converters specify the format of data in Kafka and how to translate it into Connect data. Every Connect user will
# need to configure these based on the format they want their data in when loaded from or stored into Kafka

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

# Converter-specific settings can be passed in by prefixing the Converter's setting with the converter we want to apply
# it to
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

# The internal converter used for offsets and config data is configurable and must be specified, but most users will
# always want to use the built-in default. Offset and config data is never visible outside of Kafka Connect in this format.
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000



######## /home/kafka/oracle.properties.test Configuration File 

name=oracle-connect-test1
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
topic.prefix=
connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:test/oracle@testsrv01:1521:testdb
table.whitelist=TEST1,TEST2
mode=timestamp
timestamp.column.name=CDC_TIMESTAMP

## Console Consumer

kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server kafkaserver01.localdomain:9092  --topic TEST1
```

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Kafka are you using ? This was fixed in a commit mentioned here - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/31

Comment: In server log Kafka version is seen as   0.11.0.0-cp1

Comment: that is latest version, its strange. You can ask on Kafka group regarding this, might be developers will response.

Comment: there should be some misconfiguration .

Comment: That's the Kafka server version. Make sure you're running the latest version of the connector or download Confluent platform 3.3 and use the bundled version there to make sure you have the latest connector version

Comment: Actually i am using all kafka components from Confluent platform 3.3 downloaded from Confluent website

Comment: Can you post the Connector configuration file, and the console consumer command that you're using? It could be that you're simply deserialising the data incorrectly (e.g. Avro data read as string)

Comment: Hi, I have updated question with config files and commands information. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution please add below configuration in your connector source properties

numeric.precision.mapping = true

it will disable encoding numeric value at topic

> with new version of  kafka-connect-jdbc-4.1.1

you can use property

```
numeric.mapping=best_fit
```

for best result

Comment: For a while i was working on Oracle source connector based on logminer at following URL . Now i can get data without no problem in desired format.https://github.com/erdemcer/kafka-connect-oracle